# Passing a pointer as a function argument

Tags: c++, pointers, pass-by-reference, pass-by-pointer

I am passing a pointer to a function with intent of modifying the data kept at the original address.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
void square(int **x)
{
    **x = **x + 2;
    cout<<**x<<" ";
}
int main()
{
    int y = 5;
    int *x = &y;
    cout<<*x<<" ";
    square(&x);
    cout<<*x<<" ";
    return 0;
 }
```

I am able to get the desired output using this code, i.e 5 7 7

Just wanted to know if there is a better/easy to read way of handling this.

Comment: Both [`#include<bits/stdc++.h>`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/501250) and [`using namespace std;`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/501250) are bad practice. Don't use them.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to use `int **x` instead of   just writing `square(x)` or `square(&y)` and change the function to `void square(int *x)
{
    *x = *x + 2;
    cout<<*x<<" ";
}` ?

Comment: @cdhowie, Not using them in the actual code, this is just a temporary snippet to explain my problem.

Comment: @t.niese, That is what I was looking for, Thank you so much. Could you please explain what is the difference between the two approaches as they seem to give the same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make it pass-by-reference, if you just want to perform modification on the argument through the parameter in the function.

```
void square(int& x)
{
    x = x + 2;
    cout<<x<<" ";
}
int main()
{
    int y = 5;
    cout<<y<<" ";
    square(y);
    cout<<y<<" ";
    return 0;
}
```

If you only have the pointer, you can still get the pointed object via `operator*` as [@cdhowie suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62968704/passing-a-pointer-as-a-function-argument/62968736#comment111352908_62968736).

Or pass-by-pointer is sufficient, then you don't need the intermediate pointer object `x` for passing to the function. i.e. don't need to use pointer to pointer as your code showed.

```
void square(int* x)
{
    *x = *x + 2;
    cout<<*x<<" ";
}
int main()
{
    int y = 5;
    cout<<y<<" ";
    square(&y);
    cout<<y<<" ";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the thing is I want to pass pointer to that function ( because in the actual code I want to use this for, I only have the pointer to that variable, not the actual variable )

Comment: @ShubhamChhabra You can still pass a pointed-to value by reference; dereferencing a pointer results in an lvalue reference. `int *p = &y; square(*p);`

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void square(int *x)
{
    *x = *x + 2;
    cout << *x << " ";
}

int main()
{
    int y = 5;
    cout<< y <<" ";
    square(&y);
    cout<< y << " ";
    return 0;
}
```

You don't need double indirection as per the sample code you've provided. Just pass by a pointer *instead of pointer to a pointer*.
OR, use pass by reference.